# Limit of polynomial function

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials

Good evening to everyone!
How can I solve a limit of this type. I would try l'Hospital or factoring out but it won't work for sure.
$$
\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\left|\frac{2x^7+x^2}{x^7+5x^4}\right|\right) 
$$

Thanks for any possible response.

Comment: Do you know how to compute $\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{2x^7+x^2}{x^7+5x^4}$?

Comment: No. I have no idea.

Comment: Can you predict an answer?

Comment: Once you factor it out and cancel, you find that it is no longer in indeterminate form, so L'Hospital's rule doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *equivalents*:

$2x^7+x^2\sim_0x^2$, $x^7+5x^4\sim_0 5x^4$, hence
$$\frac{2x^7+x^2}{x^7+5x^4}\sim_0\frac{x^2}{5x^4}=\frac1{5x^2}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}+\infty.$$

Comment: Why did you equivalated $2x^7+x^2\sim_0x^2$ (to this value) is there a rule that says this thing? Thanks!

Comment: It's a theorem: a polynomial is equivalent to its lowest degree term in a neighbourhood of $0$, and to its highest degree term in a neighbourhood of $\pm \infty$.

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\left|\frac{2x^7+x^2}{x^7+5x^4}\right|\right) 
$$
=$$
\left(\left|  \lim _{x\to 0} \frac{2x^7+x^2}{x^7+5x^4}\right|\right) 
$$=
$$
\left(\left|  \lim _{x\to 0} \frac{14x^6+2x}{7x^6+20x^3}\right|\right) 
$$=
$$
\left(\left|  \lim _{x\to 0} \frac{84x^5+2}{42x^5+60x^2}\right|\right) 
$$=$$
\left(\left| \frac{0+2}{0+0}\right|\right) 
$$=$$
\left(\left| \frac{2}{0}\right|\right) 
$$
$$\rightarrow \infty$$

Comment: This happens when $x \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: $x\to 0$, not $x\to \infty$

Comment: Yes I misunderstood i just correct it .